# editing music authors in whole catalog

Tags: linux, ubuntu, music-management

Is there any program that can change in custom catalogue every music file author to the name choosen before start? Something for ubuntu pls. I need it 'cause I have lot of author name variants in my folder.

Answer (score 1):

Try eyed3 utility, its package should be in standard Ubuntu repository.

Something like this should do the job:
eyeD3 -a 'Some Artist' *.mp3

Please note that you may need to provide '-1' option if your files have v.1 tags.

Answer (score 1):

Use easytag, it lets you apply changes recursively and supports more formats than just mp3. Lots of neat tools for filling in fields from filenames, that kind of thing too. It's in the repositories.